# Changing the x range gnuplot dynamically

Tags: gnuplot

How do I change x axis window range in gnuplot for dynamic run time changing data. Presently my range shows a window size from 0 to t, where t keeps increasing. But I want the range to be [t - 2000, t]. I have been looking into how to use xrange, but couldn't get it working.

I also looked at the link, but it didn't help.
[Dynamically changing the range of a histogram in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369409/dynamically-changing-the-range-of-a-histogram-in-gnuplot)

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either plot the datafile twice in your script, after the first (dummy) plot the variable `GNUPLOT_DATA_X_MAX` contains what it's name says.

Or you use the `stats` command on your data before plotting, afterwards there is a variable `STATS_max_x` that you can use to set the desired range for your plot.

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can obtain the last 2000 lines of a file with the `tail` command:

```
tail -n2000 file.dat           # if data is sorted
sort file.dat | tail -n2000    # if data is not sorted
```

The output of these commands can be plotted within gnuplot as:

```
plot "< tail -n2000 file.dat"
plot "< sort file.dat | tail -n2000"
```

This is equivalent to plot the data in the range `[xmax-2000:xmax]`.

In windows, there exists a `Sort` command, and there is a `Tail` command in the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657). You can also download the unix-commands for windows from the package [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). The syntax to call these programs are similar to the ones I have described above.